# Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommand Multiple Insert

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to add multiple rows in Table with just one connection using ((ExecuteSqlCommand)), I have no problem when all of my insert commands don't have any error.
But, for example when i send 5 insert command, and Third has error, none of 5 does not run.

Comment: do you have a code sample to show what you have ?

Comment: dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ExeCute sp_Insert id1 ,name1,lastName1  ExeCute sp_Insert id2,name2,lastName2 ExeCute sp_Insert id3,name3,lastName3  ExeCute sp_Insert id4,name4,lastName4")

Comment: You will need to wrap each statement in a try...catch.. probably not the best way but it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I find it:
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, query);